# Getting recent blog posts from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress on my site located at `www.example.com/blog`. on `www.example.com` I'd like to retrieve the top 5 latest blog posts and display date, url and blog title. Is this possible?

This means I want to get the blog posts from outside the wordpress installation using php and do a loop.

Comment: You are not telling us what you want to do - where you want to do it from.

Comment: @Emil, are you serious? others understood the question...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @Shawn & @Pekka: In the first revision, he said nothing about how he wanted it done or from where, other than "I have a blog. I want to see the latest 5 posts with date, url and title.", so I thought that was a bit to little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the RSS feed of your blog. Its a standard wordpress feature. Use a javascript (or some server side) rss client to fetch the top 5 entries from RSS feed and show it on your homepage.One such script is http://p3k.org/rss/

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query('showposts=5&orderby=ID&order=DESC');
    if($loop->have_posts()): while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
?>
    <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <span class="post-meta">
            <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
        </span>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    No recent posts yet!
<?php endif; ?>
```

See: [WordPress Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query). There are also [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/recent-posts/) to get recent posts.

Comment: @Shawn by including `wp-blog-header.php`

Comment: Wordpress 2.9.2 does not allow calls from outside, i'm going with the rss feed method.

Answer (score 1):

Use WP_Query like sugested by Sepehr and after you include wp-blog-header.php add this:

header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

This overrides WP's security check.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

in wordpress you must use blog in blog plugin. if it's use you set tempalte form your design and put the shortcode like "[blog_in_blog category_slug='my-category-slug' num=5]" in your cms page or php file and you display first 5 post with date any where in your site. you must create categories and put in short code.

blog in blog :-  http://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-in-blog/